# How to make a distinct list of integers from a list of objects?

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects, each object has property `total`.

i need to create a new `List<int>` from the above list. the problem is if two objects have `total`=4, the `List<int>` should only contain one '4'.

let my list be:

```
[
    {name: "vishnu" , total: 10},
    {name: "vishnu2", total: 11},
    {name: "vishnu3", total: 15},
    {name: "vishnu4", total: 10}
]
```

so in my list of integers the output should be:

> 10,11,15

and not:

> 10,11,15,10

Comment: could you please add your code

Answer (score 22, accepted):

using Linq:

```
myObjects.Select(obj => obj.total).Distinct().ToList()
```

Comment: Note for the future: wrapping code with '`' makes a code block (useful for inlining within a sentence), though four spaces at the start (or pressing ctrl - k while highlighting the code) provides a nicer looking block with syntax highlighting

Comment: The solution is the same

Comment: @MongZhu It was three minutes earlier. Although many claim **only** quality matters on SO there´s also a huge time-factor, making the first answer as the most noticed one.

Comment: @Rob oh goodness, it is definitely way to early for my brain. I take everything back. Sorry for my mistake

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Your answer is first, but world loves simpler things. Mark's answer was late but simple. Every one can relate to it. Its like finding needle in haystack. I would use a magnet instead of burning it all and then sieving it to find needle. Moreover the first +1 makes all the difference. After then all visitors will find mark's answer on top. BTW first +1 was from me. :)

Answer (score 5):

Why do you want to store *distinct* items in a `List<T>`? It seems to be a wrong collection type. I suggest using `HashSet<T>` which has been specially *designed for that*:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx

The implementation can be as simple as

```
HashSet<int> result = new HashSet<int>(list.Select(item => item.total));
```

Test

```
// 10, 11, 15
Console.Write(String.Join(", ", result));
```

If you insist on `List<int>`:

```
List<int> myList = result.ToList();
```

Comment: i want to show a dropdown with total no.s, so a list of int is enough ryt?

Comment: @hilda sonica: to show up distinct numbers only `myComboBox.Items.AddRange(list.Select(item => item.total).Distinct().Select(item => (object)item).ToArray());`; to show up items with their quantities: `myComboBox.Items.AddRange(list.GroupBy(item => item.total).Select(chunk => $"{chunk.Key}: {chunk.Count()} items(s)").ToArray());`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
var result = myInput.GroupBy(x => x.Total).Select(x => new 
{ 
    Total = x.Key, 
    Name = x.First().Name 
});
```

This creates a new list of anonymous type where every element has a `Toal` and a `Name`-property. However only the first element of a group is considered if more then one are gropued together.

This solution has the advantage that it persists the `Name`-properties. If you don´t need this and are only interested on the `Total`, then `Distinct` as suggested by others is easier.

Answer (score 1):

Sometning like this ?

```
using System.Linq;
...

var list = new List <YourClass>();
...
var newList = list.Select(i => i.total).Distinct().ToList ();
```